# Setting form value with params received from AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm currently designing a application where a user needs to add a store which gets their location and automatically populates the latitude and longitude fields of the new store form. I have so far been able to set up the geolocation script, as well as send the parameters to my rails controller with an AJAX call, but for the life of me I can't get the form to automatically set these values.

In my rails server log, it shows that the parameters of longitude and latitude are being passed.

From what I've read, these should be available as params[:latitude] and params[:longitude], but if I set the form value to these nothing happens.

My server log showing the params are passed:

```
Processing by StoresController#new as */*
Parameters: {"latitude"=>"-29.13184", "longitude"=>"26.195021399999998"}
User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Rendering stores/new.html.erb within layouts/application
Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.5ms)
Rendered stores/_form.html.erb (6.0ms)
Rendered stores/new.html.erb within layouts/application (10.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 38ms (Views: 31.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
```

My Rails controller with new and create actions:

```
class StoresController < ApplicationController

def new
 @store = current_user.stores.build
end

def create
    @store = current_user.stores.build(store_params)
    if @store.save
        flash[:success] = "New store was successfully saved"
        redirect_to @store
    else
        flash[:danger] = "There was an error in adding new store"
        render 'stores/new'
    end
end
```

My Geolocation Script:

```
<script>
  if (navigator.geolocation){
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(sendLocation);
    } else {
      alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
    }

    function sendLocation(position){
    var latitude  = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

     jQuery.ajax({
    data: { latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude},
    type: 'get',
    url: "/stores/new",
     });
  };
  </script>
```

My Form Partial:

```
 <%= form_for(@store) do |f| %>

    <%= f.text_field :storename, class: 'form-control',
            placeholder: "Store Name", autofocus: true %>
    </br>
    <%= f.text_field :storecode, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Store Code" %>
    </br>
    <%= f.text_field :contactname, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Store Contact" %>
     </br>
    <%= f.telephone_field :phonenumber, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Contact Number" %>
    </br>
    <%= f.text_field :latitude, :value => params[:latitude] %>
    </br>
    <%= f.text_field :longitude, :value => params[:longitude] %>
    </br>
    <div class="span1">
    <p><%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-warning btn-block" %></p>
    <p><%= link_to "Back", dashboard_path, class: "btn btn-warning btn-block" %></p>
    </div>
    <% end %>
    </br>
    <%= render '/layouts/messages' %>
```

I would like the the text_fields of :latitude and :longitude in the form to automatically receive the values of :latitude and :longitude that are passed via AJAX to the controller. Basically I want the user to be able to stand in a store and have his/her longitude and latitude passed to the controller to be automatically inserted into the form, so that the user doesn't need to manually add their coordinates.

Comment: Post your code as plain text, not an image. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: question not clear !!! can you add more details.

Comment: Sorry about that Barmar, I edited my question with the correct formatting

Comment: To sum up my question, as per my form, I would like a store to have a name, store code, contact name, contact number and then the coordinates of latitude and longitude. I want the users to fill in all details except for the coordinates, which I plan on getting via geolocation. These variable must then be sent to the controller to so that the fields of latitude and longitude are automatically populated in the new form before it is saved, because I have my model set up to validate the presence of these values. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I apologize if my question was unclear. I managed to solve it after some more research.

I simply added an id to both the latitude and longitude field, and changed my script to the following.

```
if (navigator.geolocation){
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(sendLocation);
    } else {
      alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
    }

    function sendLocation(position){
      var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
          longitude = position.coords.longitude;
       document.getElementById('latitude').value = latitude;
       document.getElementById('longitude').value = longitude;
     }
```

The forms are now populating the latitude and longitude field after finding the location.